# I want to add a label in new widget using the Qt framework

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code :

```
void maquette::on_btn_edit_clicked()
{
    QWidget* wdg = new QWidget;
    wdg->resize(320, 340);
    wdg->setWindowTitle("Modiffier");
    QLabel label1("matricule", wdg);
    label1.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100);
    wdg->show();
}
```

the window shows up but the label didn't show

Comment: Your `QLabel` is locally scoped within `maquette::on_btn_edit_clicked` and will be destroyed as soon as `maquette::on_btn_edit_clicked` finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void maquette::on_btn_edit_clicked()
{
 QWidget *wdg = new QWidget;
 wdg->resize(320,340);
 wdg->setWindowTitle("Modiffier");
 QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("matricule",wdg);
 label1->setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100);
 wdg->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the QLabel using parenting. as mentioned before.

```
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("matricule",wdg);
```

or

```
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("matricule");
label1->setParent(wdg);
```

This will make the widget float inside its parent.

You can also add the QLabel to a layout that has been assigned to the QWidget.

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
wdg->setLayout(layout);
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("matricule");
layout->addWidget(label1);
```

This will add the widget to the layout.
The layout will control how the child widgets are laid out.

Comment: thank you guys for the help